# Setting Apache environment variable on mod_rewrite rewrite condition

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

My rewrite rule is working and redirecting requests like /versioned/1234/images/foo.gif to /images/foo.gif but it doesn't seem to be setting the set_expires_header environment variable because the headers are not being appended. If I uncomment the line that explicitly sets the environment variable then the headers are set. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this? I want to be able to access the files with both URLs but only have the headers added when accessing it through the versioned URL.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev

   <Directory "/var/www/html/dev">
      Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all

      SetEnvIf Request_URI versioned set_expires_header

      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^versioned/[^/\.]+/(.*)$ /$1 [E=set_expires_header:true,L]

      #SetEnv set_expires_header true
      Header append Expires "access plus 1 year" env=set_expires_header
      Header append Cache-Control "public" env=set_expires_header
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the above configuration isn't working is that the `Header` lines are evaluated before the `RewriteRule` and thus the environment variable is always null.

The solution is to move the `RewriteRule` outside the `<Directory>` block so that it is evaluated before the `Header` lines.

See [Serving Javascript Fast](http://www.iamcal.com/serving-javascript-fast/) for more details

Here is the final working configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^versioned/[^/\.]+/(.*)$ /$1 [E=set_expires_header:true,L]

   <Directory "/var/www/html/dev">
      Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all

      Header append Expires "Mon, 28 Jul 2014 23:30:00 GMT" env=set_expires_header
      Header append Cache-Control "public" env=set_expires_header
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```