# mod_rewrite not adding REDIRECT_URL environment variable

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, virtualhost

We run a site based on Zend Framework using apache httpd (2.2) with `mod_rewrite` for SEO and usability friendly URL:s. Recently we added `mod_proxy` (and `mod_proxy_balancer, mod_proxy_http, mod_rpaf`) for setting up a loadbalancer virtual-host.

Our setup now looks like:

```
external.site.com (vhost on server1.site.com with reverse proxy)
|-internal1.site.com (vhost on server1.site.com) 
|-internal2.site.com (vhost on server2.site.com)
```

Where `internal1` & `internal2` serves most of the dynamic content and `external` serves static content plus some admin type pages. All the vhosts have got the same code and `.htaccess` setup.

The problem is that on `external.site.com` the `RewriteRule` doesn't add the correct headers to the request environment, specifically `REDIRECT_URL` which we and ZendFramework depend upon. Everything works fine for the requests that are forwarded to the internal vhosts.

The relevant parts of the httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName external.site.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/www/htdocs/
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd-proxy-access.log" combined

  <Proxy balancer://backend/>
    Balancermember http://internal1.site.com
    Balancermember http://internal2.site.com
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass /static/ !
  ProxyPass /config/ !
  ProxyPass / balancer://backend/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://backend/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName internal1.site.com

  RPAFenable On
  RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>
```

From the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/static/.*
  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off 
php_flag register_globals off
```

Because there only is a problem on the `external` vhost we assume it is a problem with the `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` combination. Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: related post: http://serverfault.com/questions/23470/setting-apache-environment-variable-on-modrewrite-rewrite-condition

Comment: Here is a similar problem [Fastcgi + mod_rewrite in Zend][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/423927/fastcgi-mod-rewrite-zend-framework-redirect-url-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe we worked around this issue by upgrading Zend Framework, later versions don't depend on REQUEST_URL. It appears REQUEST_URL has different behaviour depending on which modules are installed. See [this mailing-list thread](http://osdir.com/ml/php.zend.framework.mvc/2007-06/msg00056.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert, but I had to put [OR] to my file. As stated [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*robots.txt [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/static/.*
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: As these are two "not" comparisons, anything - including robots.txt or /static/ - will match, if you use an [OR], which means everything gets rewritten.  The goal here was to say "redirect everything EXCEPT robots.txt and /static/ to index.php", so I believe it was correct as written.

Comment: I had this problem recently - this gets messy real quick but this rule should work RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*(/static/)?(robots.txt)?$ [NC]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to your application or not but couldn't you use the content of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instead?

Comment: I'm affraid not. When using mod_rewrite REQUEST_URI is changed to reflect the URI of the script instead of the one the client requested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,E=REQUEST_URL:$ENV{'REQUEST_URL'}]
```

Basically the idea is to pick it up from one environment and just shovel it along to the next one. Not sure it that'll work but can't hurt to try.